# Foundation Zurb alerts created dynamically do not work

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I have this issue issing foundation, on my html I add in certain cases an alert dynamically like this:

```
 var alert = document.createElement("div");
 alert.setAttribute("data-alert", "");
 alert.setAttribute("class", "alert-box alert round");
 alert.innerHTML = " This is an alert test " + "<a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a>";
 document.getElementById('main').appendChild(alert);
```

Now here is the thing, when I add it dynamically, the close button does not work. However, If I directly add on the html, everything works perfect, and also even more weird, if I add one directly on the html and a few others dinamically, everything works like charm.

Any Guessing? I have all the js loaded on the footer and my code is added after all the js are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic Alert Box with Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681416/dynamic-alert-box-with-foundation)

```
$("#errorArea").append(alertBox).foundation();
```

Comment: Even if this question is a duplicate, THANKS for replying with the right answer (in name of @andresmijares25 ).